# How to save multiple variables with user input text to a file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I basically know how to do it. It works if I run the commands isolated like this:

```
@echo off
color a
Title test

:page1
set /p V1=V1=
echo Var1=%V1% >var.txt
goto page2

:page2
set /p V2=V2=
echo Var2=%V2% >>var.txt
goto page3

:page3
set /p V3=V3=
echo Var3=%V3% >>var.txt
pause
```

If I put the same thing into my main .bat file it stores just the first variable. Now I do not know if the code that I use is bad or I'm missing something in my code.

This is my main code where the variable save doesn't work:

```
@echo off
echo                                 Press a key when ready                  
echo.
set /p Name=">>>"
echo Name=%Name% >var.txt
goto page2

:page2
cls
echo %name%   ~   %username%   ~   %date%   ~   %time%
echo.
echo First question
echo.
echo bla bla bla
echo.
echo 1) bbbbb
echo 2) aaaaa
echo 3) kkkkk
echo 4) ddddd
echo 5) eeeee
echo.
set /p R1=I choose:
echo.
if not defined R1 (
goto page2
)
if %R1%==1 goto stop
if %R1%==2 goto stop
if %R1%==3 goto page3
if %R1%==4 goto stop
if %R1%==5 goto stop
echo HIT A KEY AND TRY AGAIN!
pause >nul
echo Var%R1% >>var.txt
goto page2

:page3
cls
echo %name%   ~   %username%   ~   %date%   ~   %time%
echo.
echo Question 2
echo.
echo bla bla bla
echo.
echo 1) fasfa
echo 2) asfa
echo 3) adasd
echo 4) Ix
echo 5) xx
echo.
set /p R2=I choose:
echo.
if not defined R2 (
goto page3
)
if %R2%==1 goto page4
if %R2%==2 goto page4
if %R2%==3 goto page4
if %R2%==4 goto page4
if %R2%==5 goto page4
echo HIT A KEY AND TRY AGAIN!
pause >nul
echo Var2=%R2% >>var.txt
goto page3
```

And so on. Just the name variable is written to file. :(

Comment: The only way the variables R1 and R2 get output to your text file is if the user enters in answer that you are not checking for. Basically the control of your program is not coded correctly from what I can see.

Comment: You also do not have a STOP or PAGE4 label.

Comment: your `echo`'s are different. `echo Var3=%V3% >>var.txt` versus `echo Var%R1% >>var.txt` versus `echo Var2=%R2% >>var.txt`

Comment: I have stop and page4,  but they were not necessary or relevant here. Anyway, i got your nessagew, i have to put The variabile în The file imediatly after thebuser types it. I Will Try When i arrive home and return here. I appreciate your time!

Comment: Stephan, you are correct also, but there was just a mistake at typeing. Sorry and thx for the heads up!

Comment: It works!
I put the statement imediatly after giving an input to the variable.
Thank you very much!